# p5.js sketch not working after implementing UI

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

After implementing sliders and buttons to make the sketches be able to be interactive, one sketch (matrix rain) is not working after moving where the variables are placed. Before, I declared and set them globally, now I have declared them globally an set them in the setup function so I can refresh the sketch by calling `setup()` from a function when the user wants to change the variables and play around with the sketch.

I noticed that the length of the individual column is negative, which is weird as I am using the same values as before, but got them from a slider. When I printed off the values of each variable, they all seem to be fine, just as intended.

[Here is the working version](https://editor.p5js.org/poptudor/sketches/rJvIPaB1V) - you will have to download the font file from the url inside the loadFont() function as I can't seem to find a way to link it.

[Here is the not working version](https://tudor0404.github.io/sketches/simulated/matrix%20rain/sketch-html.html)

[Here is another sketch that uses the same principal and works](https://tudor0404.github.io/sketches/simulated/linking%20dots/sketch-html.html)

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] directly in your post?

Comment: @KevinWorkman All my other sketches use the same technique and work well, I will link one of them.

Comment: We need to see the code that doesn't work. Try to isolate the problem into a small example instead of posting a link to your full page.